# How to connect an Android Emulator to a Vagrant Image on the same host?

Tags: port-forwarding, vagrant, android

I have a non-trivial application, comprised of a number of web & database servers that reside within a Vagrant image.

Port forwarding (with iptables) has been enabled on the host such that I can access the application and it's services by connecting to the Vagrant host. (The applications' development URL's are maintained in /etc/hosts; each of the developers on our team has an instance of the Vagrant image. As a result, the URL's used during development are not available via DNS.)

I need to reach the application from my Android emulators for testing; the avd's reside on the same machine I'm using to host my copy of the Vagrant image.

I've added the applications' entries to the emulator's /etc/hosts file, pointing them at 10.0.2.2 (the host machine) however the packets are not being forwarded; I suspect this is related to the way the Android Emulator does it's routing. Unfortunately, I don't see anything in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) that might help.

Here's how I'm setting up port forwarding with iptables, which works for physical devices:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
VAGRANT_IFACE=vboxnet1
VAGRANT_GUEST=192.168.50.43

FWDING_PORT=80
PORT_TO_FWD=80

echo "Forwarding port ${FWDING_PORT} to ${VAGRANT_GUEST}:${PORT_TO_FWD} on ${VAGRANT_IFACE}"
iptables -I FORWARD -d ${VAGRANT_GUEST} -m comment --comment "Accept to forward traffic" -m tcp -p tcp --dport ${PORT_TO_FWD} -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -m comment --comment "Accept to forward return traffic" -s ${VAGRANT_GUEST} -m tcp -p tcp --sport ${PORT_TO_FWD} -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -m tcp -p tcp --dport ${FWDING_PORT} -m comment --comment "redirect pckts to virtual machine" -j DNAT --to-destination ${VAGRANT_GUEST}:${PORT_TO_FWD}

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an ideal solution - and I'm not entirely certain what the difference is - but was able to resolve by port-forwarding with ssh instead of iptables, ie:

```
ssh -L :80:192.168.50.43:80 -N 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I'll leave the question open for another day or so in case someone has a better answer.

Comment: Just discovered that although this works for Android 2.x images, it won't for modern Android images; using the Nexus 5 AVD from google will forcibly steal control of VT-x which brings vagrant down hard - you'll need to quit the Android emulator before you can bring vagrant up again. (May be all x86 images... need to test further)

Comment: You can use vagrant-libvirt to avoid issues with running Vagrant + Android EMU simultaneously.